# I'm trying to pass a date parameter to my stored procedure. But it's not working to me. It's returning a error to me. How would I fix it?

Tags: sql-server, date, parameters

I'm trying to pass a date parameter to my stored procedure. But it's not working to me. It's returning an error to me. How would I fix it?

This is my stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[cadastrarFuncionario]
    @RG nvarchar(50) ,
    @Nome_Funcionario nvarchar(100) ,
    @Data_Nascimento  date
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Tabela_Funcionario(RG, Nome_Funcionario, Data_Nascimento) 
    VALUES(@RG, @Nome_Funcionario, @Data_Nascimento)
END
```

When I try to pass a date like '1996-05-05'. I got this error:

[image]

Comment: You need to put your date literal in **single quotes!** `@Data_Nascimento = '1996-05-05' `

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to put your **date literal** into **single quotes**:

```
EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[cadastrarFuncionario]
    @RG = N'19',
    @Nome_Funcionario = N'Paulo J',
    @Data_Nascimento = '1996-05-05'    -- put SINGLE quotes around your date literal!
```

Comment: @PauloJ: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998) (as soon as you can). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.